# Get computed histogram bin thresholds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have correctly applied the d3 (v 4.0) histogram function to bin an array of data. My code looks like this:

```
var bins = d3.histogram()
     .domain([data_points_min, data_points_max])
     .thresholds(8)
     (data_points);
```

Is there a function to retrieve the bin thresholds? I guess I could loop through the array and identify the max in each bin, but that would be tedious. Am guessing there must be a function, including one that produces bin thresholds that are 'pleasing to the human eye' and not some ghastly decimal number.

**Pseudo code would be something like this:**

```
var bin_thresholds = bin.thresholds();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method (as far as I know) for returning the lower and upper limits for each bin. There is one method for returning the number of bins...

```
d3.thresholdSturges(values);
```

... which is clearly not what you want, specially because you're setting the number of bins already.

However, you don't need to *"loop through the array and identify the max in each bin"*. The histogram generator generates two properties:

> - x0 - the lower bound of the bin (inclusive).
> - x1 - the upper bound of the bin (exclusive, except for the last bin).

So, you can loop through the result to get those properties only. For instance:

```js
var data = d3.range(1000).map(() => Math.random() * 20);
var bins = d3.histogram()
  .thresholds(8)(data)

bins.forEach(function(d, i) {
  console.log("Array number " + i + " --> Lower limit: " + d.x0 + " Upper limit:" + d.x1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: you don't need to set the `domain`, since you're just passing the min and max value of the array, which is the default domain:

> If domain is specified, sets the domain accessor to the specified function or array and returns this histogram generator. If domain is not specified, returns the current domain accessor, which **defaults to extent**. (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for this Gerardo, extremely useful. Quick question - what does the 'thresholds(8)' argument do? It seems to be outputting 9 bins. In my case I've noticed the number of bins output is pretty random... Is there also a way for the script to discard min and max outliers? Say, most of my data is clustered between 70-80 and then suddenly there's one data point that's 500, and that completely messes up all the bins.

Comment: It's hard to say without the data. Can you post a new question regarding this, with the data? If the data is too big, just share the minimum amount of elements to reproduce the issue. By the way, 9 bins is the expected here.

Comment: Hello Gerardo - thanks for the offer. I have done just that at the following link, and would be eager to hear what you think! Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739427/fat-tail-with-d3-v4-histogram-function-means-empty-bins